# Can I sort with context in bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, logfile

When I want to merge log files, I often use `cat logA.log logB.log | sort`. As long as the log lines start with some timestamp-like string in a common format, that's fine.

But can I somehow sort the lines *and keep lines that do(n't) follow a certain rule glued to their original leading line*? Just think of a log file where somebody logged something with linebreaks in it (without me knowing that)!

```
(berta.log)
2021-10-01 00:00:10 Hey!
2021-10-01 00:00:11 How are you doing, Adam?

(caesar.log)
2021-10-01 00:00:00 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:20 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.
    at Conversation.parseStatement
    at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement
    at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

These two log files of course would become unusable if merged with `cat berta.log caesar.log | sort`.

<sup>I also am really unsure if I should post this question to StackOverflow or to Superuser or even to Unix or ServerFault...</sup>

**Edit for clarity**

The merged logs should look e.g. like this:

```
2021-10-01 00:00:00 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:10 Hey!
2021-10-01 00:00:11 How are you doing, Adam?
2021-10-01 00:00:20 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.
    at Conversation.parseStatement
    at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement
    at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

Comment: How do you want to sort the presented input? What should be the output? What is the sorting key? `glued to their original leading line?` What is a "leading line" and which one is it? I do not understand - just `sort logA.log ; sort logB.log` if you want to sort one file at a time?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I've edited the question. The sorting key is the timestamp at the beginning of the lines. The "leading line" in this example is the `00:00:20` line that came from a string that contains a stacktrace and (thus) linebreaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic problem of mixing lines and files.

A solution: Put your multiline log lines on one line

1. Executable script: `./onelinelog.awk`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# Timestamp line
/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] / {
    if (log_line != "") { print log_line }
    log_line = $0
    next
}
# Other line
{
    # Here, I use '§' for separate each original lines
    log_line = log_line "§" $0
}
# End of file
END {
    if (log_line != "") { print log_line }
}
```

Test on `caesar.log` file:

```sh
$ ./onelinelog.awk caesar.log 
2021-10-01 00:00:00 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:20 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.§    at Conversation.parseStatement§    at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement§    at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

2. Sort:

```sh
cat <(./onelinelog.awk caesar.log) <(./onelinelog.awk berta.log) | sort
```

or

```sh
sort <(./onelinelog.awk caesar.log) <(./onelinelog.awk berta.log)
```

Output:

```
2021-10-01 00:00:00 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:10 Hey!
2021-10-01 00:00:11 How are you doing, Adam?
2021-10-01 00:00:20 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.§    at Conversation.parseStatement§    at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement§    at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

Fun ?

You may want to recover your original lines...

Use `sed`:

```sh
$ cat and/or sort ... | sed -e 's/§/\n/g'
```

or another executable awk script: `./tomultilinelog.awk`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS="§"
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 1) { print $i }
}
```

So execute:

```sh
$ cat <(./onelinelog.awk caesar.log) <(./onelinelog.awk berta.log) | sort | ./tomultilinelog.awk 
2021-10-01 00:00:00 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:10 Hey!
2021-10-01 00:00:11 How are you doing, Adam?
2021-10-01 00:00:20 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.
    at Conversation.parseStatement
    at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement
    at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

Of course, you could adapt the code and replace '`§`' character with another token.

Comment: This is a great solution which I like much more than my own. :-)

Comment: Just as an extension about the `§`: As far as I understand it, it doesn't have to be a single character, so one can choose any string that is unlikely to occur in the logs (I always recommend e.g. *PUMUCKL* (the kobold)).

Comment: I agree with you Bowi. I use in my example a 'single' char but, like in a mail content source, it's better to use a boundary token

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with another awk solution while Arnaud Valmary posted his one.

In my attempt, I just prefixed all lines that do not start with a timestamp with the last timestamp (and a number):

`prefixAllLines.awk`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
    linePattern="^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) (.*)" 
}
{ 
    if ($0~linePattern){
        number=0
        linePrefix=gensub(linePattern, "\\1", "g", $0)
        lineRest=gensub(linePattern, "\\2", "g", $0)
        printf linePrefix " " 
        printf ("%03d", number)
        printf " " lineRest "\n"
    } else {
        number+=1
        printf linePrefix " " 
        printf ("%03d", number)
        printf " " $0 "\n"
    }
}
```

So, `./prefixAllLines.awk caesar.log` brings:

```
2021-10-01 00:00:00 000 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:20 000 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.
2021-10-01 00:00:20 001         at Conversation.parseStatement
2021-10-01 00:00:20 002         at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement
2021-10-01 00:00:20 003         at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 000 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

And `cat <(./prefixAllLines.awk caesar.log) <(./prefixAllLines.awk berta.log) | sort`:

```
2021-10-01 00:00:00 000 Hey Berta
2021-10-01 00:00:10 000 Hey!
2021-10-01 00:00:11 000 How are you doing, Adam?
2021-10-01 00:00:20 000 Error: SomebodyCalledMeWithTheWrongNameException: I am not Adam.
2021-10-01 00:00:20 001         at Conversation.parseStatement
2021-10-01 00:00:20 002         at Conversation.considerReplyToStatement
2021-10-01 00:00:20 003         at Conversation.doConversation
2021-10-01 00:00:40 000 I am not Adam, I am Caesar!
```

But I like Arnaud Valmary's approach much more. :-)

Comment: Interesting solution. But if you have two or more identical timestamps in the same file or in the two files, this solution mixe all contents with the same prefix

Comment: That's right, and that's one reason why I like your approach more =)

Answer (score 0):

[*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher) can read multiple log files then print multi-line log messages from those files. It will print the log messages sorted by datetime.

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```text
s4 logA.log logB.log
```